# AJAX Call Not Working with Struts2 Spring Plugin

Tags: ajax, spring, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

I have a project with `Struts2 + Struts2 JQUery + JQ Grid + Struts2` JSON Tags. The project works perfectly and i am able to do most of the JQuery features with AJAX from tabbed panel to Grid. I have multiple struts config file and they are all called from `sj: a` tags.

But the problem starts when I add the `Spring Plugin`.

1. The Submit returns `null` values to the Action Class.
2. I have a Tabbed Panel which is created from 'struts-jquery-tags' and on `onload` calls the action class. If I use Auto wired on the Constructor in the action class only that is getting called and the action method is not getting called at all. As a result the jsp is not getting rendered.

If I remove the Spring plugin, everything works just fine. I am trying hard to overcome this issue but I have no success.

I have `Struts 2.3.3` / `Spring 3.0.5` / `aspectweaver` / `Struts2Jquery 3.3.3` jars.

Can someone advice ? I have followed `jgeppert` examples in showcase app.

Comment: you question is not clear enough to me.Spring plugin don't do anything in back-end all it do is handover the S2 specific object creation to Spring in stead of struts2 internal DI.For more problem seems more towards configuring your plugin.

Comment: Hi Umesh,  Exactly  this is the thing that is bugging me the most. I had the same concept that Spring Plugin has nothing to do with Struts2 JQuery Plugin. But If I introduce the Struts2-Spring Jar in the classpath, the ajax call stops working completely. The action class methods do not even get called. Kindly try it once (Struts2 Project with Struts 2.3.3 / Spring 3.0.5 / aspectweaver / Struts2Jquery 3.3.3 and then add Spring Plugin ) and you will be able to see the issue.

Comment: I was never a very big admirer for the jquery plugin though its really a very handy plugin and most of my jquery work rely on simple Jquery.Is it only Ajax call which not getting called or every action?